# combine queries in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

is there a possibility in Hibernate Search (lucene) to combine two different queries. For example when I want to search with 2 fields that should have one corresponding matching value:

```
firstname - John
lastname - Doe

qBuilder.keyword().onField("firstname").matching("John").createQuery());
qBuilder.keyword().onField("lastname").matching("Doe").createQuery());
```

is a way to make from this one query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Note:***  This works, but for the more Hibernate-esque approach, see my other answer

`createQuery()` returns a standard Lucene [Query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html).  So, the typical way to merge two queries in Lucene would be with a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html):

```java
Query query1 = qBuilder.keyword().onField("firstname").matching("John").createQuery();
Query query2 = qBuilder.keyword().onField("lastname").matching("Doe").createQuery();
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
//Assuming you want to require a match on both first and last names.
//If a match on either is enough, use BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD
bq.add(new BooleanClause(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
bq.add(new BooleanClause(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than use the Lucene `BooleanQuery` directly, the more Hibernate way to do this would be to use Hibernate `bool()` queries (see section 5.1.2.6 of the [documentation here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl)):

```java
Query query = qBuilder.bool()
    .must(qBuilder.keyword().onField("firstname").matching("John").createQuery())
    .must(qBuilder.keyword().onField("lastname").matching("Doe").createQuery())
    .createQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about if either the value "firstname" or "lastname" were null (in the case where the user only searched for "John", without providing "Doe")? Would we be able to use a similar query, without having to check for null values first. This is for a scenario where we have a lot of optional search parameters.

Comment: @MichaelCleverly - If the clauses should be optional,  just add them with `.should` instead of `.must`.